# displaying an array in a linked list c

Tags: c

i would like to print an array of number stored in a linked list 
it show me a big number i think it's address of the element

the first element is an intiger it's shown well , the others no 
when i displayed it inside my code it working right 
but when i use a function it doesn't work

```
        newlist->operand = (int *) malloc(max_line_length * sizeof(int));
        newlist->facteur = (int *) malloc(max_line_length * sizeof(int));

        newlist->operand[i]=op1;
        newlist->facteur[i]=shift_fact;

        r += newlist->operand[i] << newlist->facteur[i] ;
        shift_detection = 0;
        is_ready_op = false;
        is_ready_fact = false ;
        // i++ ;
        printf("%d<<%d ",newlist->operand[i],newlist->facteur[i]);//here it's working right 

        if (char_reed=='\n')
        {
             //struct_counter ++;
             newlist->result=r;
             printf(" = %d \n",newlist->result);
             printf("\n------------------------------\n");
             newlist->next=NULL;
```

[the correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGfa5.png)

and when i use this function

```
void display (node * mylist){
int i =0;
while (mylist !=NULL)
{
printf("\n****************************\n");
printf("%d =",mylist->result);
for (i=0 ; i<2;i++)
    printf(" %d<<%d",mylist->operand,mylist->facteur);
mylist = mylist->next;
}
```

}

the result will be like this
[the wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6gXP.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: `printf(" %d<<%d",mylist->operand,mylist->facteur);` -->> `printf(" %d<<%d",mylist->operand[i],mylist->facteur[i]);`

Comment: the result will bee lik this
3 = 1<<0 11867264<<11867264

Comment: the probleme still happen

Comment: Maybe the second elements of the arrays are just not initialized? (the code in the 1st fragment does not show this)

Comment: i clean it using memset function but the same thing